# Html Tags in notification.alert Phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, notifications

I have a alert in phonegap using notification.alert. It is working fine. What i want now is how can i give HTML content in its message. Something like this

```
navigator.notification.alert(
     "Call the Help Desk for assistance at: <a href="#">1(800)309-0136</a>", 
      function() { }, 
     "Having trouble signing in?"
);
```

So that when the user clicks on the telephone number i can call that number. I tried above code it simply displays the  tags as text. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use html in the notification alert body.

Instead you could use `navigator.notification.confirm` to make the call. Like this:

```
function onConfirm(button) {
    if(button == 'Call') {
        document.location.href = 'tel:1(800)309-0136';  //make the call
    }
}

navigator.notification.confirm(
    'Having trouble signing in?',                                            //title
    'Do you want to call the Help Desk for assistance at 1(800)309-0136?',   //message
     onConfirm,                                                              //callback
    'Call,Exit'                                                              //buttonNames
);
```

Comment: Thank you So much @DZL... I have implemented the workaround as you mentioned.